# Stop View Rotation in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there a way to stop screen rotation on a specific view?  I need to have rotation enabled on my main screen but then disabled once a game mode is chosen.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by "on a specific view" you mean "in a specific view controller"? If so, you can just override `- [UIViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]` in this one view controller to return only the orientations that you support on that screen:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your AppDelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [MainScreen class]])
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```